# Вставка данных в фрагменты из FragmentPagerAdapter сразу после запуска приложения

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

У меня есть приложение, которое заключается в перелистывании фрагментов на главном экране приложения. Не смотря на простоту, у меня возникает проблема. Суть в том, что эти фрагменты должны заполняться данными сразу после запуска приложения, но я не могу найти метод, который вызываеться ПОСЛЕ полного отображения фрагментов и приложения, но ПЕРЕД передачей управления приложением пользователь (то есть onResume() не подходит). Есть ли такой метод? Можно ли реализовать это как-то по другому?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TableFragment MonFragment;
private TableFragment TueFragment;
private TableFragment WedFragment;
private TableFragment ThuFragment;
private TableFragment FriFragment;
private TableFragment SatFragment;
private TableFragment SunFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SectionsPagerAdapter pagerAdapter =
            new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
}

 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();                  
    MonFragment.setL8("123321"); //Попытка изменить значение в одном из EditText`ов на последней стадии создания приложения
}

private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 7;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) { //Это фрагменты. В каждом из фрагментов 13 EditText`ов и кажый из них при запуски приложения нужно заполнить некоторыми значениями.
            case 0:
                return new TableFragment();
            case 1:
                return new TableFragment();
            case 2:
                return new TableFragment();
            case 3:
                return new TableFragment();
            case 4:
                return new TableFragment();
            case 5:
                return new TableFragment();
            case 6:
                return new TableFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getResources().getText(R.string.monday);
            case 1:
                return getResources().getText(R.string.tuesday);
            case 2:
                return getResources().getText(R.string.wednesday);
            case 3:
                return getResources().getText(R.string.thursday);
            case 4:
                return getResources().getText(R.string.friday);
            case 5:
                return getResources().getText(R.string.saturday);
            case 6:
                return getResources().getText(R.string.sunday);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        // save the appropriate reference depending on position
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                MonFragment = (TableFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
            case 1:
                TueFragment = (TableFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
            case 2:
                WedFragment = (TableFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
            case 3:
                ThuFragment = (TableFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
            case 4:
                FriFragment = (TableFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
            case 5:
                SatFragment = (TableFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
            case 6:
                SunFragment = (TableFragment) createdFragment;
                break;

        }
        return createdFragment;
    }

}
```

}

Код фрагментов (TableFragment):

```
public class TableFragment extends Fragment {

private EditText l8;
private EditText l9;
private EditText l10;
private EditText l11;
private EditText l12;
private EditText l13;
private EditText l14;
private EditText l15;
private EditText l16;
private EditText l17;
private EditText l18;
private EditText l19;
private EditText l20;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_table, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    l8 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.l8);
    l9 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.l9);
    l10 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.l10);
    l11 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.l11);
    l12 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.l12);
    l13 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.l13);
    l14 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.l14);
    l15 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.l15);
    l16 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.l16);
    l17 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.l17);
    l18 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.l18);
    l19 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.l19);
    l20 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.l20);
}

//SETTERS


public void setL8(String t8) {
    l8.setText(t8);
}

public void setL9(String t9) {
    l8.setText(t9);
}

public void setL10(String t10) {
    l8.setText(t10);
}

public void setL11(String t11) {
    l8.setText(t11);
}

public void setL12(String t12) {
    l8.setText(t12);
}

public void setL13(String t13) {
    l8.setText(t13);
}

public void setL14(String t14) {
    l8.setText(t14);
}

public void setL15(String t15) {
    l8.setText(t15);
}

public void setL16(String t16) {
    l8.setText(t16);
}

public void setL17(String t17) {
    l8.setText(t17);
}

public void setL18(String t18) {
    l8.setText(t18);
}

public void setL19(String t19) {
    l8.setText(t19);
}

public void setL20(String t20) {
    l8.setText(t20);
}
```

}

Лог ошибки:

```
2021-03-07 18:55:36.413 6837-6837/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.trayvor.table, PID: 6837
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.trayvor.table/com.trayvor.table.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.trayvor.table.TableFragment.setL8(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4444)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4476)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.trayvor.table.TableFragment.setL8(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.trayvor.table.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:52) <----
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1456)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4434)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4476) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: OnViewCreated()?

Comment: @Crush

Не подходит, крашиться при заполнении полей во фрагменте. пример: 

Override
    public void onViewCreated(NonNull View view, Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        l8.setText("123"); <---- здесь приложение вылетает
    }

если вы про метод, который в классе фрагмента

Comment: l8 точно проинициализировано перед заполнением текстом? NPE вылет? Код нужен и лог ошибки. =)

Comment: @Crush код добавил

Comment: l8 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.l8); и т.д. перенесите в onCreateView()

Comment: @Crush Это ничего не поменяло. Из чего бы я не вызывал setL8() и.т.д, приложение вылетает

Comment: Лог ошибки еще приложите.

Comment: @Crush добавил лог ошибки

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120540/discussion-between-crush-and-trayvor).